# Is it possible to implement a token filter chain in elastic search with an UNDO step?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-indexing

I need a token filter chain for these filter rules:
* Remove all stopwords
* If the token list is now empty, then restore the stop words

Reason: I have to find, for example, the book "It" by Steven King.

Any guidance help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `synonym` filter to change `it` to `_it_` for example: `it => _it_` and at searching time you use an analyzer that uses the same synonym filter.

Comment: But with this solution I'll got the "it" from "How it Works Annual" in my index. Right?

Comment: Yes. I don't think there is an easy way out of this though. If you build your own token filter, separate from the default `stop` one, how would your filter know that the `stop` filter removed anything? The filters are standalone and separate. Maybe, at indexing time, you don't index `it` but something else (like `_it_`) for those documents where you know that specific stopword shouldn't be removed.

Comment: Thanks. My idea now is to work with 2 indices - one with and one without stopwort filter. At question time I'll deal with their results.

Comment: Why don't you use two fields in the same index: one with `stop` filter and one without?

Comment: Ups, yes, that's what I meant.